# SQLAlchemy foreign keys mapped to list of ids, not entities

Tags: sqlalchemy

In the usual `Customer` with `Order`s example, this kind of SQLAlchemy code...

```
data = db.query(Customer)\
    .join(Order, Customer.id == Order.cst_id)\
    .filter(Order.amount>1000)
```

...would provide instances of the Customer model that are associated with e.g. large orders (`amount > 1000`). The resulting Customer instances would also include a list of their orders, since in this example we used `backref` for that reason:

```
class Order:
    ...
    customer = relationship("customers", backref=backref('orders'))
```

The problem with this, is that iterating over `Customer.orders` means that the DB will return complete instances of Order - basically doing a 'select *' on all the columns of Order.

What if, for performance reasons, one wants to e.g. read only 1 field from Order (e.g. the id) and have the `.orders` field inside Customer instances be a simple list of IDs?

```
customers = db.query(Customer)....
...
pdb> print customers[0].orders
[2,4,7]
```

Is that possible with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this optimally - with array aggregation:

```
data = db.query(Customer).with_entities(
    Customer,
    func.ARRAY_AGG(
        Order.id,
        type_=ARRAY(Integer, as_tuple=True)).label('order_ids')
    ).outerjoin(
        Orders, Customer.id == Order.cst_id
    ).group_by(
        Customer.id
    )
```

This returns tuples of (CustomerEntity, list) - which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make a query this way:

```
(
    session.query(Customer.id, Order.id)
    .select_from(Customer)
    .join(Customer.order)
    .filter(Order.amount > 1000)
)
```

It doesn't produce the exact result as what you have asked, but it gives you a list of tuples which looks like `[(customer_id, order_id), ...]`.

I am not entirely sure if you can eagerly load `order_ids` into `Customer` object, but I think it should, you might want to look at [joinedload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload), [subqueryload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.subqueryload) and perhaps go through the [relationship-loading docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html) if that helps.

In this case it works you could write it as;

```
(
    session.query(Customer)
    .select_from(Customer)
    .join(Customer.order)
    .options(db.joinedload(Customer.orders))
    .filter(Order.amount > 1000)
)
```

and also use [noload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.noload) to avoid loading other columns.